# Flume "OR Regex" Filtering Interceptor

Tags: regex, expression, filtering, interceptor, flume

I'm a newbie with Flume and I can't find enough information about regular expressions – that's why I need help with this.

I'm trying to make a Regex Filtering Interceptor.

I have some events like these:

```
[20151010][type1][stuff]
[20151011][type2][stuff]
[20151012][type3][stuff]
[20151013][type4][stuff]
[20151014][type1][stuff]
[20151015][type2][stuff]
[20151016][type3][stuff]
```

I would like to make a regex filter to include type1 and type2.

The result should be:

```
[20151010][type1][stuff]
[20151011][type2][stuff]
[20151014][type1][stuff]
[20151015][type2][stuff]
```

Is it possible to make just 1 filter? 
Or maybe should I multiplex the information and make two different filters?

Answer (score 0):

Using [RegexInterceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-filtering-interceptor), events can be filtered with OR operator as below,

```
 agent.sources.source_3.interceptors.filters.type = regex_filter                                    
 agent.sources.source_3.interceptors.filters.regex = .*type1.*|.*type2.*                    
 agent.sources.source_3.interceptors.filters.excludeEvents = false
```

By the way, this is just how regex works in scala/ java too, examples

### Pattern

```
scala> import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Pattern

scala> import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Matcher

scala> val pattern = Pattern.compile(".*type1.*|.*type2.*")
pattern: java.util.regex.Pattern = .*type1.*|.*type2.*
```

### matcher 1

```
scala> val matcher = pattern.matcher("[20151010][type1][stuff]")
matcher: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*type1.*|.*type2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=]

scala> val matches = matcher.matches()
matches: Boolean = true
```

### matcher 2

```
scala> val matcher = pattern.matcher("[20151011][type2][stuff]")
matcher: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*type1.*|.*type2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=]

scala> val matches = matcher.matches()
matches: Boolean = true
```

### matcher 3

```
scala> val matcher = pattern.matcher("[20151011][type3][stuff]")
matcher: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*type1.*|.*type2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=]

scala> val matches = matcher.matches()
matches: Boolean = false
```

If you look at their [implementation code](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/d9c9a7dd9a6889ecf6b9dc88fb8e02ccc1cd5167/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/interceptor/RegexFilteringInterceptor.java#L104), they are using `matcher.find()`

```
scala> val pattern = Pattern.compile(".*type1.*|.*type2.*")
pattern: java.util.regex.Pattern = .*type1.*|.*type2.*

scala> val matcher = pattern.matcher("[20151010][type1][stuff]")
matcher: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*type1.*|.*type2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=]

scala> val matches = matcher.find()
matches: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score -1):

OR is nice and easy in regex: just use `|`. So you would want something that looks like:

```
type1|type2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still can't see the solution. 
¿The result should be something like this? 
    agent.sources.s_name.interceptors.i_name.regex=*."type1|type2".*